# How to solve this quiz functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. I have a quiz with 3 possible answers, one is correct and the other two are wrong. I have two functions which return me the righ number of correct/wrong answers if i use  but if i want to use type="checkbox" how can i improve my functions condition

   ```
   var correct_at=0;
   var wrong_a=0;
   function checkQs(s){
     var qs= document.getElementsByName(s);
     var noOfRadios = qs.length;

     for(var i=0;i < noOfRadios; i++)
     {
       if(qs[i].checked)
       {
           if(qs[i].value=="correct")
           {
               text2display=text2display + "This one is correct.\n";
               correct_a++;
           }
           else 
           {
               text2display = text2display + "The correct answer to the quiestion : " + answers[questions.indexOf(s)];
               wrong_a++;
               break;  
           }
       }
     }
   }

   function checkAll(){
     for (var i=0; i< questions.length; i++) 
     {
       checkQs(questions[i]);
     }
     var message = 'Correct questions: ' + correct_a;
     message += ' and wrong questions: ' + wrong_a + '.\n';

     var box = document.getElementById('answersBox');
     box.value = text2display + message;
   }
   ```
2. When the user push the button "start test" i want my quenstions to appear one by one , after he answered one he goes to the next by pressing the button "Go to next question". I used this jquery function

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('ol').find('li:visible:first').ready(function(){
       $('ol > li').hide();
       $('button').click(function() {

           if 
               ($('ol > li:first').is(':visible'))
               $('ol > li:visible:last').next().show();
           else
               $('ol > li:first').show();
       });
   });
   ```

But with this function when i start the test none of the questions are visible, the first appears only after i hit the button "Go to next question". So how can i make the first one visible and the rest hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Call "Go to next question Button" Click function in the "Star test Button" click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $('#btnStart').click(function() {
       //....
       $('btnNextQuest').click();
    });
});
```